# Monitoring custom graph in CONKY

Tags: conky, cpufreq

How to monitor a custom graph in [**CONKY**](http://conky.sourceforge.net/). Right now I display the single values of the CPU frequency in GHz:

```bash
CPU1: ${exec echo "scale=1; $((`cpufreq-info -c 0 -f`)) / 1000 / 1000" | bc | awk '{printf "%1.1f\n", $0}'} GHz 
CPU2: ${exec echo "scale=1; $((`cpufreq-info -c 1 -f`)) / 1000 / 1000" | bc | awk '{printf "%1.1f\n", $0}'} GHz
CPU3: ${exec echo "scale=1; $((`cpufreq-info -c 2 -f`)) / 1000 / 1000" | bc | awk '{printf "%1.1f\n", $0}'} GHz
CPU4: ${exec echo "scale=1; $((`cpufreq-info -c 3 -f`)) / 1000 / 1000" | bc | awk '{printf "%1.1f\n", $0}'} GHz
```

[image: conky cpu freq]

My aim is to display the CPU frequency an its changes in graphical plot. *Thought I'm still not sure what will be the best kind of plot for it. I have something like this in mind, but I'm open for any better suggestion:*

[image: graph example]

**How can I monitor a custom graph in CONKY?**

Comment: There's no need to use `${exec}` to display CPU frequency. It calls 4 external processes to get 4 frequencies. There are `${freq N}` and `${freq_g N}` for that. N sets the core number. First variable show frequency in MHz, the second - in GHz.

Comment: Just curious if any progress was made with this? I was just thinking of a graph of 800Mhz to 3500Mhz for my conky.

Answer (score 0):

you should use something like **`execigraph`**.

```
${color 556B2F}${execigraph 2 ssh user@Bananapi top -bn 1 | awk 'NR>7{s+=$9} END {print s"%"}'}
```

On local system, styling the **`cpugraph`** would be quit easier.

Comment: According to: http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html `execigraph` takes two switches `-t` and `-l`. Any idea what they do? (time related I believe).

Comment: `-l` makes the vertical graph scale *logarithmic*. Conky graphs can have two colors supplied. Without `-t`, vertical sections of the graph start at one color, and slowly fades to the second color as they scroll left. With `-t`, each vertical section of the graph is colored according to its height, and remains the same color as it scrolls.